# Details of File command in linux

Tags: linux, file

I was looking for a command to check incase i have any binary character in my files.
While browsing from different blogs got to know that .. file command will give u the proper details of it.

So fired following command on my files and got the following details :

```
file filename*

filename1: data
filename2: ASCII English text, with very long lines
filename3: empty
filename4: ASCII text, with very long lines
filename5: ASCII text
```

It would be great if someone could explain me this details.

Thanks in advance .. !!

Comment: type in ``man file`` on your server and read it

Comment: I get the sense that there may be a more interesting question behind your _RTFM_ question.  To me check whether a file has "any binary characters" means that one wants to see whether a file that is expected to be text of a certain encoding (e.g. ASCII UTF-8) contains any non-text data.  If so, you need to take a step back and write a much clearer question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file type with data are binary files:

> filename1: **data**

Empty type means that the file is empty:

> filename3: empty

ASCII text with very long lines type means the file type is of ASCII and it is more than 300 characters long.

You can check the manual and examples from the link below:
http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ufile.htm